# PDF specification for appending

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I am writing some code that needs to be able to take two pdfs and append them on the page level (for example, if they were both 2 page documents, have one 4 page document where all 4 pages are identical to the original).

Without using a library what's the best way to do this?  Does the PDF specification make this easy?

Comment: Without using a library of code, very first thing to do is *write one*.

Comment: Doing this from scratch is not a trivial task.  There's a 700+ page spec of the PDF document format out there floating around (a simple google search should be able to locate this).  Either using a free library, or bite the bullet and use a commercial library, depending if this is a personal or commercial grade project you're working on.

Comment: As already pointed out, there's a simple reason why PDF libraries exist (and you should adopt one of them for your convenience): PDF is a massive spec which typically requires a significant implementation effort even to address the simplest task. @user2366842 I would say that FLOSS libraries may also be suitable for commercial-grade projects, depending on your requirements (on the other hand, I often experience poor-quality PDFs generated by some closed-source proprietary products, so when it comes to quality there's no prejudicial distinction).

Comment: The other comments already say why you should use a library but I'm curious about the "why" of not using a library.in your requirements.

Comment: Since I needed to do only one thing with the pdfs, and it sounded like a simple thing, I was hoping to be able to do it by hand.
Paulo - I wanted to implement it in javascript, and save the appended PDF to the user's computer using a actionscript wrapper and their filewriter API.  I couldn't find a pdf javascript library, and I would be surprised if their was one.  Also it would probably be big and I would only need a small part of it.

Comment: Unfortunately even to just merge two documents into one, you need a rather significant amount of the spec implemented, I believe.  It does more than simple page concatenation behind the scenes (it has to rebuild the file's indexes, rebuild all the metadata, etc.)

Comment: and sorry for the double post, but pushing this off to the client in javascript might not be wise anyways, as there's no way to tell if a client even has javascript enabled (or if they're using a low powered device - for example, an older cellphone - this is a fair amount of work for such a device).  This really should be done server side if possible.  To do this in javascript, both documents would have to be pushed over the wire first, then assembled on their end.  This would require some pretty aggressive presumptions of the client end.

Comment: ".. I would be surprised if there was one." Well -- I wrote a PDF object parser in pure JS. In that implementation I was unable to use typed arrays and so it was horribly slow, and I abandoned it in pursue of more useful things to do. But I agree on the comment above it may not be the smart thing to do anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have already mentioned, merging two PDF files together will be a large undertaking, if you don't use a PDF library. You will need a solid understanding of the internal PDF structure. Here is a link to the PDF specification. It's a good place to get started - [PDF Reference](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf).

Before I go into detail, here is a little experiment in merging two very simple PDF files, and the result. The two files are 34kb each. The resulting file was 35kb, and it contained the pages of each of the input files. That alone shows that there is more going on under the hood than merging the code for the two input documents. Comparing the code for the input and output documents, also showed that they have been completely re-created, with different object IDs for each object.

A usual PDF document contains a header, body, cross-reference table and a trailer. 
When a PDF document is read, the library starts from the top, and then jumps to the end of the document, moving back, until it hits the cross-reference table. In this table, the library looks for the objects, and byte offsets in a particular document. This table is updated, or re-created when new objects are added to the document.

To merge two documents manually, you will have to move the objects from the body of the second document into the first document. Then you can update the metadata of the first document if necessary. The difficult task here is updating, and possibly re-creating the cross-reference table. You will need to implement a significant portion of the PDF spec to be able to do that.

If you decide to use a library in your project, there are some fairly lightweight libraries out there that will do the trick. The [PDFtk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) library is fairly lightweight, and can do PDF merging with 1 command. It has a free version, as well as command line capabilities. You should be able to set up a simple server to host it in your environment, and then call it via Java Script.

In case your project requires more than a free library, then there is [APDFL](http://www.datalogics.com/products/pdf/pdflibrary/), which is a commercial PDF processing library. It has a .NET or a Java interface, so you can easily create a server app that will merge PDF files for you.

Comment: You have to recreate the file and recreate the cross-reference table in almost all cases, simply because objects are numbered and there likely will be classes between the object numbers in both files. But that is not a very difficult task by itself, as the cross reference table is simply an index to where each object lives in the file: book-keeping in other words. What is difficult is the merging aspects that you mention, the fact that in many cases you don't have to repeat certain objects because you only need them once... But to do it simple, I think you can skip most of those aspects.